# Preview Camera HTC-One cuts image

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, preview, htc-android

I'm using a custom camera preview on my app, it works fine in almost all devices, for HTC-One I'm getting a bad cut, the original photo doesn't match what the preview shows on the top.

It only happens on this device, this is the code of my preview camera and the picture about what's going on.

Thanks in advance for any help someone can give me.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private Context context;
private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;

public CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;
    if (mCamera != null) {

        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for (Camera.Size str : mSupportedPreviewSizes) {
            Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);
        }

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    }

    float ratio;
    if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width) {
        ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
    } else {
        ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

public void setFlash(String flashMode) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(flashMode);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

    if (sizes == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;


    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;

        if (Math.abs(size.height - h) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - h);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - h) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - h);
            }
        }
    }

    return optimalSize;
}

public void switchCamera(Camera camera) {
    Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    } else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }

    setCamera(camera);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Camera preview size and picture size are two different parameters, which you can update through setPictureSize() and setPreviewSize() APIs. But if user doesn't change these sizes, it will use default values.

In this case you are updating the preview size by calculating optimum preview size based on some aspect ratio. But you are not updating picture size, so it will be using default picture size.

If picture size and preview size aspect ratios are different, definitely the captured image looks different from preview. So update the picture size also by calculating optimum picture size with same aspect ratio as preview size.